# Scanning with BLE on a device with API level less than 21

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-5.0-lollipop

I see in the Android API [that it is possible](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html) to use `startLeScan()` to scan for BLE devices on API levels as low as 18. Unfortunately, this method is now deprecated and the recommended alternative is `startScan()`, which is only [available on API levels 21+](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeScanner.html#startScan(java.util.List%3Candroid.bluetooth.le.ScanFilter%3E,%20android.bluetooth.le.ScanSettings,%20android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback)).

Since API level 21 is only available on Lollipop or higher (approx. 30% of all devices), I would prefer to use `startLeScan()` as it hits a larger portion of devices, but I'm not sure how to go about this. Should I create different implementations for each API level, or is it simply not viable to create an application using BLE scanning on versions lower than Lollipop?

Comment: I would recommend doing seperate implementations. Otherwise you might not see the best performance on API 21+.